# ASP NET MVC5 compiler publish error in IIS (works fine in VS2015)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm development an ASP NET MVC 5 app. In Visual Studio 2015 work fine, but when I try publish in IIS I obtain the next error:

```
CS0103: the name 'model' does not exist in the current context.

Línea 1:  @using Name.Models
**Línea 2:  @model LoginViewModel**

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R ...

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, 
but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the
latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# 
programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240
```

In previous publications of the same project I had no problem.

Comment: Do you have `System.Web.Mvc` in your publish packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the problem! The web.config of the Views folder had been excluded from the project. We added it and everything worked again.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

ASP not registered in IIS

> aspnet_regiis -i

Read more about it from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx)